# Decrypt string from oracle in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, encryption

I have encrypted fields in Oracle that are added to SQL Server tables. I have been trying to decrypt the fields in C# program, but does not work or i get exceptions given below.
Here is the encryption and decryption logic in Oracle

```
g_cset varchar(10) := 'AL32UTF8';
g_static varchar(32) := '!20R8QO__RKEEJ+*>;I:V?U=:F 4?T9L';
g_key raw(250) := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data =>g_static,dst_charset => g_cset);
g_enc_type PLS_INTEGER := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256+dbms_crypto.chain_cbc+dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5;

Encryption happens here
dbms_crypto.encrypt(src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(pValue,g_cset),typ=>g_enc_type, key=>g_key);

Decryption here
utl_i18n.raw_to_char(dbms_crypto.decrypt(src=>pValue,typ=>g_enc_type,key=>g_key),g_cset);
```

Below is the code in C# i tried for decryption

```
            string toDecrypt = "D869C2E0895B822465925C1C41F11339";
            var binaryFromString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toDecrypt);
            
            var aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("!20R8QO__RKEEJ+*>;I:V?U=:F 4?T9L");
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


            var decryptBytes = aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(binaryFromString, 0, binaryFromString.Length);
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This code gives exception as

```
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed
```

If i change padding as below, program output wrong decrypted value

```
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None
```

I had refereed some of the links here, i have made use of the most but none worked. Some of the solutions have IV assigned to AesManaged object, i'm not sure what to assign here. I tried to use AesCryptoServiceProvider instead of AesManaged that too did not work.

Comment: Decryption is possible if `toDecrypt` is hex decoded (and not UTF8 encoded) and a zero IV (16 _0x00_ values) is used: _10 Denewood_.

Comment: @Topaco That worked!! 
Can i ask how did you know the toDecrypt had to be hex decoded and IV to have zero. I could not make that out from Oracle?

Comment: Educated guesses: 0-9, A-F are hex digits. CBC uses an IV. Often a zero IV is used when none is specified.